# save dictionary data into .xls file

Tags: python-2.7, xlwt

I have a dictionary like this:-

```
{u'qty_on_hnd': 33.0, u'brand': u'A PORTELA', u'barcode': u'APORTELAMENCIO', u'qty_case': 12.0, u'descrip': u'MENCIA 2012', u'type': u'WINE-IMP/SPAIN', u'price': 22.99, u'size': '1500ML'}

{u'qty_on_hnd': 21.0, u'brand': u'ABAD DOM BUENO', u'barcode': u'APORTELAMENCIO', u'qty_case': 12.0, u'descrip': u'GODELLO 2013', u'type': u'WINE-IMP/SPAIN', u'price': 16.99, u'size': '750ml'}
```

I want to that each key become column name and rest value store in each row with respective key.My dict name is brand_dict.
Is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `brand_dict.keys()` for column name and over `brand_dict.values()` for a row

```
for x, column_name in enumerate(brand_dict.keys()):
    worksheet.write(0, x, column_name)

for x, cell_value in enumerate(brand_dict.values()):
    worksheet.write(1, x, cell_value)
```